# Graphic like apple watch one

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

Thank you all for your replies. My new fixed circleView now is: import UIKit

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    private let progressLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let  backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    private var progressLabel: UILabel

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        progressLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        createProgressLayer()
//        createLabel()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        progressLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createProgressLayer()
//        createLabel()
    }

//    func createLabel() {
//        progressLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), 60.0))
//        progressLabel.textColor = .whiteColor()
//        progressLabel.textAlignment = .Center
//        progressLabel.text = "Load content"
//        progressLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 40.0)
//        progressLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        addSubview(progressLabel)
//        
//        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: progressLabel, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
//        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: progressLabel, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
//    }

    private func createProgressLayer() {
        var arcWidth: CGFloat = 3
        var arcBgColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.94, blue:0.94, alpha:1.0)

        let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
        let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 2 + M_PI_2)
        let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

        let centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 , CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2)

        let gradientMaskLayer = gradientMask()
        progressLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius: CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - 30.0, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath
        backgroundLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - 30.0, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath

        backgroundLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        backgroundLayer.lineWidth = 15.0
        backgroundLayer.strokeColor = arcBgColor.CGColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)

        progressLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        progressLayer.fillColor = nil
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 15.0
        progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0


        gradientMaskLayer.mask = progressLayer
        layer.addSublayer(gradientMaskLayer)
    }

    private func gradientMask() -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds

        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

        let colorTop: AnyObject = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 213.0/255.0, blue: 63.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let colorBottom: AnyObject = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 198.0/255.0, blue: 5.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let arrayOfColors: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.colors = arrayOfColors

        return gradientLayer
    }
//    
//    func hideProgressView() {
//        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
//        progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
//        progressLabel.text = "Load content"
//    }

    func animateProgressView() {
//        progressLabel.text = "Loading..."
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = CGFloat(0.0)
        animation.toValue = CGFloat(0.7)
        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.delegate = self
        animation.removedOnCompletion = false
        animation.additive = true
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        progressLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }

}
```

But I would really like to know now how to:

Do this with the corners, to leave like apple watch one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS38u.png)

and how to move the percentage label, from 0 to 70%, I mean, to animate from 0 to 70 at the same time the circle animates.

Comment: Please search before asking. This has been covered hundreds of times on SO.

Comment: Store you draw percent in variable, and in drawRect before drawing do like var += val;, and use var to draw right circle line. Also don't forget to restrict var min and max values.

Comment: I have already done what you said to me, but i'd like to get the graphic as the apple watch one. Is  there anything i can do? Maybe with the corner radius? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "*Do this with the corners*"? Show us what your current code generates. If you're talking about the rounded ends of the stroked path, you'll want to set the [`lineCap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/lineCap) of the `CAShapeLayer` to `kCALineCapRound`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to use a CAShapeLayer and animate the `strokeEnd`. Otherwise you'll just have to draw all the intermediate shapes yourself and create your own animation.

Comment: What Matt said. (voted.) Animating yourself using drawRect is generally more CPU-intensive, harder to do, and the results don't look as good. Use Core Animation.

Comment: @matt Thank you. I have already done the circle animation, but what should I do to get the background circle, in order to get the same effect as before? I'll upload my new code here.